# Android Studio instead of Flutter

Tags: java, android, firebase, flutter, android-studio

I am a 4th-year student and I did a mistake while choosing the technology stack for my project android app. I went on to build my app through the android studio and not flutter, as I thought flutter would be difficult to build in given the time constraints, I was evidently misinformed. Now, what if the interviewer asks why did you choose android studio over flutter. What arguments can I use to support my answer?

Comment: You can google them actually.

Comment: If you feel you made a mistake, simply say so and explain why you would make a different decision now. Then maybe talk about problems you overcame to make it work in android studio. Good luck!

Comment: Truth is always the best answer.

Comment: `as I thought flutter would be difficult to build in given the time constraints,` there's your answer. So long as you've completed the task and it meets the requirements that response holds weight.

Comment: few advantages of native apps built with android studio ,  less app size , better performance , not every thing is supported in flutter yet , Larger developer community so easy to find solutions to your problems . 
In my opinion kotlin is much better and fun language to work with than dart .

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve this question

Answer (score 1):

1. Android Studio is IDE  for building application where flutter is Framework for build Android and iOS application(Both).
2. We use java/kotlin in android studio for build android application.
3. For flutter we need Mac Os because iOS application do not run on windows and linux.
4. Dart language use in application buliding using flutter.

I hope you understand what is diffrence of Android studio and flutter. You can easily answer him(interviewers) as you can say i was familiar with java/kotlin .

Answer (score 0):

I think you got a bit confused. Android Studio and Flutter can't be compared to one another. As Umesh said above, Android Studio is an IDE which helps you develop more easily, whereas Flutter is a framework which we use for building mobile apps.
Actually, you can do Flutter development on Android studio. There's no problem of using both of them.